# Possible to perform a self-redirect in Golang httptest server?

Tags: unit-testing, http, go, redirect

I'm trying to write a unit test that involves an `httptest` server that redirects to itself a specified number of times before redirecting to some other `httptest` server. So, something like this:

```
import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
)

func redirectService(numRedirects int) (*httptest.Server) {
    simpleHost := simpleService()
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        numRedirects--
        if numRedirects > 0 {
            http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusSeeOther)
        } else {
            http.Redirect(w, r, simpleHost.URL, http.StatusSeeOther)
        }
    })
    host := httptest.NewServer(mux)
    return host
}
```

This clearly doesn't work, as the URL passed to `Redirect` can't be relative. But I can't get the full URL of the service until after the mux has already been created. Is there some other way to accomplish this?

Comment: Something like this? https://play.golang.org/p/4k6epMWDQHy or the following should work as well I think https://play.golang.org/p/RLCCmmHUDYs.

Comment: Or you could try `r.URL.String()` i.e. using the incoming request's own url.

Comment: play.golang.org/p/4k6epMWDQHy totally works! It seems wild to me that you can do stuff like that. Thanks much!!

(r.URL.String() is returning "/", so seems that isn't an option.)

Comment: "The URL passed to Redirect can't be relative." That's incorrect: ["Redirect replies to the request with a redirect to url, *which may be a path relative to the request path*."](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Redirect)